# Laravel: Can't pass a Browser test using RefreshDatabase trait

Tags: mysql, laravel, selenium, laradock

My test will fail if I use RefreshDatabase trait.

**Without the trait -- test will pass but data remains in database.**

I'm using:

- Laravel 5.5 (a fresh one)
- Laradock: nginx mysql selenium

Tests are being running from a laradock's workspace.

This is the test, simple, from an official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/dusk#creating-browsers).

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;

class LoginTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /**
     * A Dusk test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testLogin()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        // dump('wait...');
        // sleep(15);
        // dump('go!');

        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
            $browser->visit('/login')
                    ->type('email', $user->email)
                    ->type('password', 'secret')
                    ->press('Login')
                    ->assertPathIs('/home')
            ;
        });
    }
}
```

`dump/sleep/dump` is just to see if the user has been created in the database. **It's not!**

The result of `php artisan dusk` is:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Browser\LoginTest::testLogin
Failed asserting that '/login' matches PCRE pattern "/^\/home/u".

/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/MakesAssertions.php:53
/var/www/tests/Browser/LoginTest.php:32
/var/www/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/TestCase.php:92
/var/www/tests/Browser/LoginTest.php:34
```

NOTE:
Asserting text *"These credentials do not match our records."* will be true, so I believe that user has never been created.

Comment: are you using an `sqlite :memory:` connection?

Comment: Only if it is set by default.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/73

Answer (score 1):

In [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk#migrations) document has mentioned:

> Most of the tests you write will interact with pages that retrieve data from your application's database; however, your Dusk tests should never use the `RefreshDatabase` trait. The `RefreshDatabase` trait leverages database transactions which will not be applicable or available across HTTP requests. Instead, use the `DatabaseMigrations` trait, which re-migrates the database for each test:

So the answer is using `DatabaseMigrations` instead of `RefreshDatabase`

Answer (score 0):

Use `DatabaseMigrations` trait instead of `RefreshDatabase` trait.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the problem is using sqlite/pgsql/whateversql driver.
And I sure you don't need to put something like `$app['config']...` lines to `\Tests\CreatesApplication::createApplication`.

I solved this problem running `artisan config:clear` before `artisan serve`.
It will make new phpunit.dusk.xml which will route to `.env.dusk.{env}`, and then rerun dusk command.